# Weird whitespace in TXT record

Tags: dns, dkim

We've added a TXT record for DKIM validation (copy-pasted the DKIM string), but there seems to be a weird character in the record that:

- doesn't appear at all in the DNS manager
- doesn't appear at all in the [DKIM Core](http://dkimcore.org/c/keycheck) validator
- do appear as empty quotes in the [mail-tester.com](https://www.mail-tester.com) validator
- do appear as a whitespace within quotes during `dig` in Linux

This character makes the DKIM invalid, so my questions are: What is it, why isn't it detected and how do I remove it?

---

DKIM Core:
[image]

---

mail-tester.com:
[image]

---

Dig output:

```
dkim._domainkey.example.com. 3600 IN    TXT "v=DKIM1\; k=rsa\; g=*\; s=email\; h=sha1\; t=s\; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDKCyTnwDTY7yp1Xd/ApOgq7rzfSB8N2s+cX0sHzpwAt/I60KGGLV/qq/Wx462PX7LiL9O9UngvjoH6VILDJAnS3xGVHkVXIC9lzPcgTREV56AisCfIXa9t6ZELvXDAHJY1YfghPOUlh0KnXzL37W2hwTj4J3tJt1iEeKNgYnEwxQ" "IDAQAB\;"
```

Comment: I see now that the length of the whole TXT record is over 255 characters - can this be the issue?

Comment: You can just simplify your DomainKey in DNS, `k=rsa;p=<Your Public key>` leave all the items off, it's not needed. This should keep you under the 255 length. Also test using [mailtest](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/resources/emailauthentication/), it's more comprehensive then the others.

Answer (score 6):

### Quick answer

The DKIM specification ([RFC 6376 Sec. 3.6.2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6376#section-3.6.2.2)) dictates that

> Strings in a TXT RR MUST be concatenated together before use with no intervening whitespace.

In other words: The whitespace in between the strings does not have any relevance. The strings inside the quotes are simply processed as one.

### Technical background

`TXT` records consist of what's called character strings. Each of these consists of up to 256 bytes, where the first byte ("octet") carries the length of the string (see [RFC1035 Sec. 3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#section-3.3)). When displayed, character strings are typically bounded by quotes `"` on either side ([RFC1035 Sec. 5.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#section-5.1)). The quotes are not stored and don't count towards the length.

That means that if the value is no more than 255 bytes long (plus quotes), one character string suffices. If it is longer, the `TXT` record will contain multiple character strings ([RFC1035 Sec. 3.3.14](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#section-3.3.14)).

The interpretation of the multiple character strings depends on the specific scenario, and for DKIM it is specified as described above. So, what you are seeing is a technical artifact, and not an erroneous space.